# How to shellexecute a tempory installer file?

Tags: c++, winapi, shellexecute

```
SHELLEXECUTEINFO shExecInfo;

shExecInfo.cbSize = sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFO);

shExecInfo.fMask = NULL;
shExecInfo.hwnd = NULL;
shExecInfo.lpVerb = _T("runas");
shExecInfo.lpFile = filePath;
shExecInfo.lpParameters = NULL;
shExecInfo.lpDirectory = NULL;
shExecInfo.nShow = SW_MAXIMIZE;
shExecInfo.hInstApp = NULL;

ShellExecuteEx(&shExecInfo);
```

If the filepath is the temp file downloaded from the Internet, ShellExecuteEx would fail. But if filepath is normal file name such as "notepad", it do works.

I conclude that shellexecute need the right extension name, but normal privilege app could not write an executable file to the system partion such as c:\users\xxx\local\temp\xxx.exe.

The error code is ERROR_NO_ASSOCIATION.

Please help me solve this contradiction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error that the system is returning to you is `ERROR_NO_ASSOCIATION`. Although you have not stated what extension `filePath` has, it seems likely that it is not `.exe`.

Were you to rename the downloaded file to have extension `.exe`, then the call to `ShellExecuteEx` would succeed. That's the hacky way to do it. The cleaner way is to use the `lpClass` member of the `SHELLEXECUTEINFO` struct to specify that you want the file to be treated as an executable. You can do that by adding the following to your code:

```
shExecInfo.fMask = SEE_MASK_CLASSNAME;
shExecInfo.lpClass = _T("exefile");
```

I'd write your code like this:

```
SHELLEXECUTEINFO shExecInfo = {0};
shExecInfo.cbSize = sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFO);
shExecInfo.fMask = SEE_MASK_CLASSNAME;
shExecInfo.lpVerb = _T("runas");
shExecInfo.lpFile = filePath;
shExecInfo.nShow = SW_MAXIMIZE;
shExecInfo.lpClass = _T("exefile");
ShellExecuteEx(&shExecInfo);
```

Note the zero initialization so that we can omit explicit assignment for members that should be `NULL`.